# Incorrect date with psutil.boot_time() on windows

Tags: python, pyinstaller, psutil

I am using python 3.5.

I have a python script using psutil.  For my local workstation it is displaying the correct time since last reboot when I call psutil.boot_time().  On the target server, 2008 r2, it is showing the wrong time.  "Net statistics server" reports the server has been up since December 2015 but psutil.boot_time says its been up since the 2nd of Feb 2016.  Is there a known issue with running this on windows?  I have compiled the script into an exe file on the server using pyinstall. Is it possible that is causing an issue?  I'm not sure how to test short of doing a full python install on the server to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C source:

```
// XXX - By using GetTickCount() time will wrap around to zero if the
// system is run continuously for 49.7 days.
```

Is it about 49.7 days off?

EDIT: source is
https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/python/psutil/psutil/_psutil_windows.c

Comment: Well that's a surprise.  But it lines up perfectly with the time.  Thanks for finding that!  I did some looking and this has been an issue for a while.  One possible solution I saw on a Perl forum was to use the time stamp on C:\windows\bootstat.dat.  Since it is supposedly only touched at boot.  I did find this on msdn: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx].  It mentions using  GetTickCount64 to correct it.  Probably not as simple as that...

Comment: @oljones It *is* as simple as that. That tick count is stored in 64 bits instead of 32 bits. The max number of days jumps from 49.7 to 213,503,982,335. That's 213 billion days, or 584 million years.

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed this in psutil: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/761